# How to pass parameters by position to stored procedure using dapper?

Tags: c#, parameters, dapper

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
   Train result = connection.Query<Train>("Trains.AwesomeSauce", new { TrainId =  "TRN001", CurrentTrack = "TR001"}, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).FirstOrDefault<Train>();
}
```

The above method works, but I want to pass the parameters without actually saying this = that. The method below does not work I get an error that says

> Additional information: Procedure or function 'AwesomeSauce' expects parameter '@TrainId', which was not supplied

Code:

```
public void TestMethod5()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        List<string> parameters = new List<string> { "TRN001", "TR001" };
        var list = connection.Query<Train>("Trains.Awesomesauce", new { parameters}, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).FirstOrDefault<Train>();
    }
}
```

I also tried the code below, but got the same

> Procedure or function 'AwesomeSauce' expects parameter '@TrainId', which was not supplied

error.

```
public void TestMethod5()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        var dictionary = new object[] { "TRN001","TR001"}
        .Select((item, ind) => new { ind = ind.ToString(), item })
        .ToDictionary(item => item.ind, item => item.item);
        DynamicParameters p = new DynamicParameters(dictionary);
        Train train = connection.Query<Train>("Trains.Awesomesauce", param: p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).FirstOrDefault<Train>();
    }
}
```